Ethers.js and Web3
In this when I try to npm run dev it then State: {provider: null, signer: null, contract: null, account: '0xed5ab183a181b754bf47aa8c940685b969fe8b57'}
The account gets populated every time but the contract, provider, and signer fields remain null.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Web3Provider')
    at connectWallet

And I have used the BrowserProvider thing but this is not giving the contract function.
So if you can help me that would be really helpful.
And the address of the contract and everything else is correct.
App.jsx
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import abi from './contract/Todo.json';
import Navbar from './Component/Navbar';
import Data from './Component/Data';

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    provider: null,
    signer: null,
    contract: null,
    account: null,
  });

  const connectWallet = async () => {
    const contractAddress = "0x49461D2B6f9EEb8179e125c3d5F731E40fb8D55c";
    const contractABI = abi.abi;
    try {
      const { ethereum } = window;
      if (ethereum) {
        const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
        if (accounts.length > 0) {
          const provider = new ethers.provider.Web3Provider(ethereum);
          const signer = provider.getSigner();
          const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractABI, signer);

          setState({ provider, signer, contract, account: accounts[0] });
        } else {
          setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, account: null }));
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Ethereum object not found, install Metamask.");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    connectWallet();

    const handleAccountsChanged = (accounts) => {
      if (accounts.length > 0) {
        setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, account: accounts[0] }));
      } else {
        setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, account: null }));
        console.log("Please connect to MetaMask.");
      }
    };

    window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', handleAccountsChanged);

    const checkAccounts = async () => {
      const { ethereum } = window;
      if (ethereum) {
        const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_accounts" });
        if (accounts.length === 0) {
          setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, account: null }));
        }
      }
    };

    const interval = setInterval(checkAccounts, 1000);

    return () => {
      window.ethereum.removeListener('accountsChanged', handleAccountsChanged);
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  console.log('State:', state);

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar state={state} />
      <Data state={state} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


package.json
{
    "name": "client",
    "private": true,
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
        "preview": "vite preview"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
        "@mui/material": "^5.15.21",
        "ethers": "^5.7.2",
        "react": "^18.3.1",
        "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.1",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
        "eslint": "^8.57.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.7",
        "postcss": "^8.4.39",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.4.4",
        "vite": "^5.3.1"
    }
}

I have also tried with the latest ethers version still no luck.
